# How create TypeLiteral without string/writer when using ts-morph?

Tags: typescript, ts-morph

I want to create type files like this programatically:

```
export type Car = {
    color: string;
    // ... tons of properties
};
```

Thats seems pretty easy using `ts-morph` addTypeAlias method:

```
sourceFile.addTypeAlias({
    name: 'Car',
    type: theType,
    isExported: true,
});
```

Though unfortunately `theType` here must be `string | WriterFunction`.
And I want it to be a TypeLiteral! Is there a way to this with `ts-morph` that I am missing? Ofcourse I could construct my type literal as a string by some looping and string concatenation etc, but I would really like to avoid building my files that way - then I might as well use template/stub files and fs.

Any other way to do this in a more programmatic/Node-class based approach?

Comment: Doesn't type.getText() do what you need? https://ts-morph.com/details/types#text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Let's consider the following Node.js version as the current version:

```
$ node --version
v18.13.0
```

Let's consider the following npm version as the current version:

```
$ npm --version
9.2.0
```

Let's consider the following versions of the dependencies as the current versions (an excerpt from the `package.json` file):

```json
{
  <…>,
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-morph": "17.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "10.9.1"
  }
}
```

## Overview

> Though unfortunately `theType` here must be `string | WriterFunction`. And I want it to be a TypeLiteral! Is there a way to this with `ts-morph` that I am missing?

Currently, it seems there is no straightforward solution.

Please, see the following seemingly related GitHub issues:

- [[Question] How to create a TypeLiteral ? · Issue #1333 · dsherret/ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/issues/1333).
- [adding types like classes/interfaces · Issue #529 · dsherret/ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/issues/529).
- [TypeNode - Add methods for manipulating types · Issue #546 · dsherret/ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/issues/546).

> Any other way to do this in a more programmatic/Node-class based approach?

Let's consider some possible solutions.

## Possible solution: `ts-morph`: Use object type writer (`Writers.objectType()` static method)

It may be considered as more programmatic, but it is still a writer-based (not a node-based) approach.

References:

- The `Writers.objectType()` static method. [ts-morph/Writers.ts at 17.0.1 · dsherret/ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/blob/17.0.1/packages/ts-morph/src/structurePrinters/Writers.ts#L55).
- The corresponding tests. May serve as documentation. [ts-morph/writersTests.ts at 17.0.1 · dsherret/ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/blob/17.0.1/packages/ts-morph/src/tests/structurePrinters/writersTests.ts#L48).

### Draft example

#### `src/index-ts-morph.ts` file

```js
import { Project, WriterFunction, Writers } from "ts-morph";

async function createFile(outputFilePath: string) {
    const project = new Project();
    const sourceFile = project.createSourceFile(
        outputFilePath,
        undefined,
        { overwrite: true }
    );

    const typeAliasDeclarations = [
        createExportedTypeAliasDeclaration("Book"),
        createExportedTypeAliasDeclaration("House"),
        createExportedTypeAliasDeclaration("Car"),
    ];
    sourceFile.addTypeAliases(typeAliasDeclarations);

    await sourceFile.save();
};

function createExportedTypeAliasDeclaration(name: string) {
    const writerFunction: WriterFunction = Writers.objectType({
        properties: [
            {
                name: "color",
                type: "string"
            }
        ]
    });
    return ({
        name: name,
        type: writerFunction,
        isExported: true,
    });
}

await createFile("output.ts");
```

#### Running script and checking its output

```
$ npx ts-node src/index-ts-morph.ts
$ cat output.ts 
export type Book = {
        color: string;
    };
export type House = {
        color: string;
    };
export type Car = {
        color: string;
    };
```

Please, note the strange indentation.
Probably, it is caused by a `ts-morph` defect?

## Possible solution: `typescript`: Use `typescript` instead of `ts-morph`

References:

- Current revision. [Using the Compiler API · microsoft/TypeScript Wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API/167d197d290bec04b626b91b6f453123ef309e58).

### Draft example

#### `src/index-typescript.ts` file

```js
import { writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import ts from "typescript";
const { factory } = ts;

async function createFile(outputFilePath: string) {
    const typeAliasDeclarations = [
        createExportedTypeAliasDeclaration("Book"),
        createExportedTypeAliasDeclaration("House"),
        createExportedTypeAliasDeclaration("Car"),
    ];

    const printer = ts.createPrinter({
        newLine: ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed
    });
    const nodes = factory.createNodeArray(typeAliasDeclarations);
    const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
        "this-name-is-ignored.ts",
        "",
        ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,
        false,
        ts.ScriptKind.TS
    );
    const printedString = printer.printList(
        ts.ListFormat.MultiLine,
        nodes,
        sourceFile
    );

    await writeFile(outputFilePath, printedString);
};

function createExportedTypeAliasDeclaration(name: string) {
    const colorPropertySignature = factory.createPropertySignature(
        undefined,
        factory.createIdentifier("color"),
        undefined,
        factory.createTypeReferenceNode(
            factory.createIdentifier("string"),
            undefined
        )
    );

    return factory.createTypeAliasDeclaration(
        [
            factory.createToken(ts.SyntaxKind.ExportKeyword)
        ],
        factory.createIdentifier(name),
        undefined,
        factory.createTypeLiteralNode([
            colorPropertySignature
        ])
    );
}

await createFile("output.ts");
```

#### Running script and checking its output

```
$ npx ts-node src/index-typescript.ts
$ cat output.ts 
export type Book = {
    color: string;
};
export type House = {
    color: string;
};
export type Car = {
    color: string;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TypeLiteral type from the typescript library to define the properties of your type Car and then pass it as the type argument to addTypeAlias method in tsmorph.

```
 import { TypeLiteral } from 'typescript';

const carProperties = [
  { name: 'color', type: 'string' },
  // ... tons of properties
];

const typeLiteral = new TypeLiteral(
  carProperties.map(prop => {
    return {
      name: prop.name,
      type: prop.type,
    };
  })
);

sourceFile.addTypeAlias({
  name: 'Car',
  type: typeLiteral,
  isExported: true,
});
```